# Laravel 4.2 Handling 404, 403, and 500 Errors and Exceptions

Tags: php, laravel-4, error-handling, laravel-5

I use Laravel 4.2 and want to handle 404, 403, and 500 Errors, I found this code on GitHub:

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code)
{
    $message = $exception->getMessage() ?: 'Exception';

    if (Config::get('app.debug')) {
        return;
    }

    switch ($code)
    {
        case 403:
            return Response::View( 'error.403', compact('message'), 403);

        case 500:
            return Response::view('error.500', compact('message'), 500);

        case 404:
            return Response::view('error.404', compact('message'), 404);

        default:
            return Response::view('error.404', compact('message'), $code);
    }
});
```

but it didn't work. and I found this code work good to handle 404 only

```
App::missing(function($exception)
{
    return Response::view('error.404', array(), 404);
});
```

Comment: Did you test with laravel debug turned off? As you see, function returns null if that is turned on.

Comment: Thank you for help, it worked when I removed the first two conditions, but I feel that there is lake in my code. `$message = $exception->getMessage() ?: 'Exception';

    if (Config::get('app.debug')) {
        return;
    }`

Comment: @Mohamed Did you removed the code you show or remove the first two cases of 403 and 500?